# from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse returning NO url link

Tags: python, django

in my urls.py, i've defined url as

```
url(r'^deals/(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{2})/(?P<slug>.*)/$','deals.views.deal_detail', name="deal_detail"),
```

when i try to use 'get_absolute_url' as follows

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return '/deals/%s/%s/%s/' %(self.pub_date.strftime("%Y"),
        self.pub_date.strftime("%m"),
        self.slug)
```

this works fine for me but when i use

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
def get_absolute_url(self):
    year = self.pub_date.strftime("%Y")
    month = self.pub_date.strftime("%m")
    slug = self.slug
    return reverse('deal_detail', arg=[year,month,slug])
```

it returns no url to href tag. Any suggestions/help please

Comment: Should be 'args' instead of 'arg'.

Comment: Cool. Wrote it as an answer you can accept it and the question doesn't appear unanswered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a typo. It should be 'args' not 'arg.

`return reverse('deal_detail', args=[year,month,slug])`